# Если сообщение в чате начинается с запятой, номер адресуемого сообщения не раскрывается в имя

Tags: дефект, нытьё, чат

В чате можно ответить на любое сообщение. Тогда моё сообщение начинается с номера, а после отправки выглядит как начинающееся с имени автора адресуемого сообщения.

Однако, если начать с запятой, то происходит вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка на чат: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31163922#31163922

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы запятая появлялась после обращения автоматически.

Comment: @PavelMayorov и пробел после запятой чтоб не потерялся.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Не нахожу это дефектом. Чтобы сообщение считалось ответом, требуется, чтобы оно начиналось как `:123456`, то есть двоеточие-число-пробел. Именно такая комбинация вставляется автоматически, если щёлкнуть по иконке ответа.

Удаление значимого пробела нарушает структуру сообщения. Такое происходит повсеместно, и не считается дефектом: например,

1.Один
2.Два

не распознаётся как список из-за отсутствия пробелов.

Comment: Что плохо: если оставить пробел, он так и останется после имени. А хочется, соблюдая правила русского языка, после обращения поставить запятую.

Comment: Достаточно распознавать двоеточие-число в начале сообщения (и проблема исчерпана)

Comment: @NickVolynkin С точки зрения русского языка перед обращением не ставится "@", поэтому я не считаю эту конструкцию частью предложения.

Comment: Вот чего заминусили-то? Автор не разработчик SO и не виноват в таком поведении сайта.

Comment: @NickVolynkin несогласие. Оправдание этому приводится: "так уж устроена система". А вопрос именно о том, что она, возможно, устроена не вполне правильно.