# @Username, нам нужна запятая!

Tags: предложение, статус-отклонено, чат

В продолжение вопроса "[Если сообщение в чате начинается с запятой, номер адресуемого сообщения не раскрывается в имя](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3420/%d0%95%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80)".

В русском языке правильно ставить запятую после обращения. Текущая реализация чата не позволяет это сделать:

- Если поставить запятую сразу после номера адресуемого сообщения, номер не раскрывается в имя: `:123456, нам нужна запятая!`
- Если добавить (оставить) пробел, то он остаётся в отображаемой строке перед запятой: `@Username , нам нужна запятая!`. Это тоже неверно.

Собственно, предложение: добавлять после @Username запятую и пробел. Будет так:

```
@Username, нам нужна запятая!
```

Совершенно неожиданно, в английском языке тоже есть такая норма. Называется как-то вроде "[commas in vocative case](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/4898/20112)". Поэтому предлагаемое изменение окажется верным для подавляющего большинства пользователей чатов.

Comment: Да зачем? Мало знака `@` и подсвечивания? Это же не официальная бумага к кому-либо, а, все таки, чат. А для него этого достаточно. А так можно уж тогда добавлять `Уважаемый, Вася Пупкин` и заканчивать `Приятного вечера/дня/ночи`, `C уважением, Ваш Петя Зубкин`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, спасибо. :)

Comment: Да, особенно спасибо! ))) кстати в комментариях тогда тоже, для единообразия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С большой вероятностью подобный функционал не будет реализован. Как минимум несколько причин, которые бросаются в глаза.

- Упоминать участника можно не только в начале, но и в конце, где запятая после будет лишней, а вот до, было бы хорошо добавить.
- Если вы публикуете ответ, но вместо текста используете лишь изображение, имя участника, кому вы отвечаете, не отображается вовсе.
- Механизм упоминаний в комментариях на основном сайте и в чате должен быть более или менее [однотипен](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139959/274323).

Comment: Надо не запятую добавлять, а при парсинге её просто корректно обрабатывать. В комментариях запятая работает. А вот [в чате](//chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31407298#31407298) вместо имени пользователя остаётся число - нехорошо.

Comment: @Qwertiy  [Согласно спецификации](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/) в чате можно использовать только форму `@имя`. Для такой формы упоминания запятые в чате работают.